# How can I convert an alphanumeric and use it for calculation?

Tags: cobol, openvms

I will read a sequential file which include some string such as "79.85", "1000", "212.34".

I want to convert the alphanumeric into number in this format 00000.00 ?

I will need to add up these numbers and move it to a field in the format 0000000.00 .

I tried:

```
01 WS_AMOUNT_TXT                                PIC X(8).
01 WS_AMOUNT                                    PIC 9(5).9(2).

MOVE WS_AMOUNT_TXT(1:8) TO WS_AMOUNT(1:8).
```

What I got is unexpected, the string is just as same. It is left align and no leading  zero display.

How can I made it right align and have leading zero?

**EDIT: I tried the suggestion by NealB, and it sadly failed:**

```
01 WS_AMOUNT_NUM                                PIC 9(5)V9(2).
01 WS_AMOUNT_DISPLAY                            PIC 9(5).9(2).
01 WS_AMOUNT_TXT                                PIC X(8).


        DISPLAY WS_AMOUNT_TXT

        COMPUTE WS_AMOUNT_NUM = FUNCTION NUMVAL (WS_AMOUNT_TXT)
        MOVE WS_AMOUNT_NUM TO WS_AMOUNT_DISPLAY
```

79.85  << this is what was displayed when I called DISPLAY WS_AMOUNT_TXT
AND THEN IT CRASHED.

%COB-F-NUMVALARGINV, NUMVAL or NUMVAL-C argument invalid
%TRACE-F-TRACEBACK, symbolic stack dump follows
  image    module    routine             line      rel PC           abs PC
 DEC$COBRTL                                 0 000000000001F2B8 000000007C2F72B8
 DEC$COBRTL                                 0 0000000000014764 000000007C2EC764
 DEC$COBRTL                                 0 0000000000014C44 000000007C2ECC44
 DAILY_SPLIT_REFUND_ADJ  DAILY_SPLIT_REFUND_ADJ  DAILY_SPLIT_REFUND_ADJ
                                          121 00000000000003C4 00000000000303C4
 DAILY_SPLIT_REFUND_ADJ                     0 00000000000313A0 00000000000313A0
                                            0 FFFFFFFF80271EF4 FFFFFFFF80271EF4

Comment: It failed because whatever was in WS_AMOUNT_TXT could not be converted to a valid numeric value. You have some "junk" in that field other than digits, a decimal point and/or spaces. Clean up WS_AMOUNT_TXT before trying to convert it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the intrinsic function [NUMVAL](http://www.openvms.compaq.com/doc/73final/6296/6296_profile_039.html#index_x_872)
to do the conversion. Something like...

```
    01 WS-AMOUNT-TEXT     PIC X(8).  
    01 WS-AMOUNT-NUM      PIC 9(5)V9(2).  
    01 WS-AMOUNT-DISPLAY  PIC 9(5).9(2).  

    COMPUTE WS-AMOUNT-NUM = FUNCTION NUMVAL (WS-AMOUNT-TEXT)  
    MOVE WS-AMOUNT-NUM TO WS-AMOUNT-DISPLAY
```

NUMVAL converts the text representation of a number into a numeric type. Use the numeric data type: `PIC 9(5)V9(2)` in your calculations. Then use `MOVE`
to convert the numeric result into a displayable amount with explicit decimal point.

Note: If you have a lot of calculations to perform, it might be best to use a `PACKED-DECIMAL` data type to improve efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Use redefine.

01 WS-AMOUNT-TXT-GRP.
   03 WS-AMOUNT           PIC X(4).
01 WS-AMOUNT-NUM REDEFINES  WS-AMOUNT-TXT-GRP PIC 9(4).

After re=licating value in WS-AMOUNT-TXT-GRP or in WS-AMOUNT, automatically value will replicate in WS-AMOUNT-NUM

Comment: Did you read the question? The input is of left-aligned "numbers", which may contain and actual decimal-point. They need to be added together. Your suggestion won't work.